# Are questions about learning or practicing nonverbal communication or body language on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

Books on leadership will often assert that anywhere from 2/3 to 80% of communication is nonverbal - that is, expressed in tone of voice, posture, eye contact, and gestures rather than the specific vocabulary, conjugations, or grammatical structures used. Are questions about *learning* or *practicing* such nonverbal communication on-topic?

To be clear, I'm not talking about signed or manual languages such as American Sign Language (ASL) that are not spoken but have specific grammar and vocabulary, but about so-called "soft skills" in communication. For example, see [this](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/nonverbal-communication-skills-2059693) article from The Balance Careers.

Obviously, we already have a close reason for "grammatical rules or specific characteristics of a language", so questions like "Please interpret the posture of the person in this video" or "For how many seconds should I make eye contact in order to convey sincerity?" are likely already inherently off-topic, but I could see someone asking questions like "How do I find a partner to practice eye contact with?", "How do I assess my level of ability in reading someone's attitude to the topic of discussion from their posture?", or "Is there a certification in using body language effectively?".

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, body language is part of communication and some of it is specific to a few specific cultures, and hence languages (separating language and culture as two fully independent topics never works in my experience). I'm learning Korean at the moment and they have quite a few very ostentatious body signs that you need to learn if you want to be very proficient (C2 level) in in-person conversations that make it quite evident to me that learning body signals is part of learning a language.

However, most people will not think of body signals first when they think of learning a language, which I suppose will lead to very few questions on body language. If they're not very numerous, I doubt they would be a cause for concern, so why ban them?

I also think the guidelines you mentioned for appropriate questions about body language are fair and in keeping with the "What topics can I ask about here?" guidelines.